# order numbers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this code which orders the numbers starting from the biggest one but its kinda confusing for me:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 const int n=5;
 int i, j, t, a[n]={15,9,8,7,5};

 cout << "a[]={";
 for(i=0; i<n; i++) cout << a[i] << " ";
 cout << "} \n\n";

 for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
   for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
     if(a[i]>a[j]){
       t=a[i];
       a[i]=a[j];
       a[j]=t;
     }

 cout << "Pas radhitjes inkrementuese \n\n"
      << "a[]={";
 for(i=0; i<n; i++) cout << a[i] << " ";
 cout << "} \n\n";


 cin.get();cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

**Is there any other way to order numbers from 1 array, starting from the biggest/lowest number?**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: What you have is known as "bubble sort". You have the tell-tale double-loop and swap.

Comment: Just for informational sake, there are many different sorting algorithms. Which one is most efficient depends on what the expected input is like, how many items there are to be sorted, and at least a few other considerations.

Comment: just a simple array like this: a[n]={15,9,8,7,5}. I need to sort the elements of that array for example starting from the biggest number: 15,9,8,7,5 but with an algorithm not with std::sort.

Comment: Specify which algorithm you want it to be ! If its is nothing but, just sort it and its okay ! use a clearer version of bubble sort itself. you have the code for all the algorithms here - http://mathbits.com/mathbits/compsci/arrays/sorting.htm . I suggest you play with all the algorithms because this looks like a basic educational question and trying out all algorithms will help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there is the selection sort, insertion sort, merge sort, quick sort, heap sort, etc. You can find a lot of information regarding the particular implementation around the web. If you want an easy way without regards to the actual implementation of the sorting algorithm, you can use `std::sort` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

`std::sort` is the usual way to go when sorting stuff

Answer (score 0):

you can just edit your code to this

```
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
   for(j=0; j<n-1; j++)
```

if you want more optimal sort you can use one of sorting algorithm on

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You have the codings and explanations for all the algorithms - http://mathbits.com/mathbits/compsci/arrays/sorting.htm

I suggest you to try all the algorithm and it would help if in case of the educational learning.